# removing DOM element on jQuery not working

Tags: jquery

so. I've used a prototype that will create a div element (var $mainDiv) with several other elements inside, when this is called i get a small widget box.
this div element is nested inside a div called wrapper (id wrapper).

later on i created this function:

```
$dismissButton.click(function() { 
    $("#wrapper").remove($mainDiv);
});
```

because when i click the dismiss button (nested inside the div and part of the widget box) i want it to make the entire box disappear.

it's not working.
what am i doing wrong? (also tried `.empty()` )

Comment: You want to remove `#wrapper` or `$mainDiv`?

Comment: you try `$("#wrapper").remove($mainDiv); ` ? you can show jquery and html?

Comment: my bad, it's not detach i used, its remove(), empty() and detach, all 3 of them

Barmer, i want to remove maindiv and everything inside it upon button click

Comment: show more html and jquery

Comment: how do i post a code in the fast comment properly? (the code is too long though)

Comment: Also consider using something like jsfiddle.net

Comment: @RanST Don't post code in comments, edit the question. And use the `{}` code markup tool to make it literal code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove `$mainDiv`, it should be:

```
$mainDiv.remove();
```

`.remove()` removes the elements that the method is applied to. If you use an argument, it should be a selector that filters the set of elements. E.g.

```
something.remove(selector);
```

is equivalent to:

```
something.filter(selector).remove();
```

In your case, since `$mainDiv` is not one of the elements in `$("#wrapper")`, it didn't remove anything.

Comment: so.
first, you get the "genius of the day" award. many thanks

second, just so i won't stuck in this in the future. 
as i started the creation of the box, i appended maindiv to wrapper. therefore i was certain that maindiv is one of the elements in wrapper
so i need a small explanation on this

all in all, it works. many thanks.

Comment: I don't know what `new notification()` does. That's not a standard Javascript class, it's something in your code.

Comment: this is an object i can call with argument ofcourse. 
this problem is solved. now i have this thing... i create several boxes and they stack, one on top of another. when i click the button they are all gone together.

I managed to give each box a specific id (lets call it random id, althogh it's not really random, but at least they're not all called "main-div") but the problem remains

Comment: I know it's an object. But without knowing what the object does, it's impossible for me to guess what's going wrong. You need to post a new question, and show the details of this object.